# How to create a new matrix from output of another matrix using loops and functions?

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement, matrix

How can I create a function *points ()*, that takes matrix *goals* as input, with 2 columns and where the number of rows depend on the input of the user? The first column is for the home goals and the second column is for the away goals. How can I get the goals matrix, that the function takes a second input *win_points* that specifies the number of points a team receives for a win?

Points are for example, 3 points for winning, 1 for equal score, 0 if lost. So if a team wins 1-0, the win_point matrix should be displayed as 3 0, if a team plays 4-4, the win_point matrix should be displayed as 1 1 in points.

I also tried it like this, but I think with **function** it will work better.
I used for my code now a matrix of 10 rows and 2 columns, the rows should be flexible (that you can put every amount of rows) and the columns should be 2 fixed, because there are only 2 teams in a match.

What did I do wrong in the code below?

```
set.seed(1)
goals1 <- matrix(sample(0:5, size = 5*2, replace = TRUE), nrow=5, ncol=2)
points1 <- matrix(0, nrow(goals1),ncol(goals1))
for(i in 1:nrow(goals1)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(goals1)) {
    if goals1[goals1[i]>goals1[j]] {
      points1[i] <- 3
      points1[j] <- 0
    } else if goals1[goals1[i]<goals1[j]] {
      points1[i] <- 0
      points1[j] <- 3
    } else if goals1[goals1[i]==goals1[j]] {
      points1[i] <- 1
      points1[j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

First of all, thanks for the answer with the correct code! But why isn't this code above working? I do not understand what I am doing wrong in my code. CAN SOMEONE EXPLAIN PLEASE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple vectorized function that takes as parameters the score matrix, the number of points for a win (defaulted to 3), and the number of points for a draw (defaulted to 1). Then, we can use the win and draw points as multipliers for logical comparisons of the scores in each match. No need for loops here.

```r
points <- function(goals, win_points = 3, draw_points = 1)
{
  
  data.frame(home = win_points * as.numeric(goals[,1] > goals[,2]) + 
                    draw_points * (goals[,1] == goals[,2]),
             away = win_points * as.numeric(goals[,2] > goals[,1]) + 
                    draw_points * (goals[,2] == goals[,1])) |>
    as.matrix()
}
```

So, creating a random matrix of goals, we get:

```r
set.seed(1)

goals <- matrix(sample(0:5, size = 10*2, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=2)
colnames(goals) <- c("Home", "Away")

goals
#>       Home Away
#>  [1,]    0    0
#>  [2,]    3    4
#>  [3,]    0    4
#>  [4,]    1    1
#>  [5,]    4    5
#>  [6,]    2    5
#>  [7,]    5    1
#>  [8,]    1    0
#>  [9,]    2    4
#> [10,]    2    4
```

And we can get the points matrix from the goals matrix as easily as:

```
points(goals)
#>       home away
#>  [1,]    1    1
#>  [2,]    0    3
#>  [3,]    0    3
#>  [4,]    1    1
#>  [5,]    0    3
#>  [6,]    0    3
#>  [7,]    3    0
#>  [8,]    3    0
#>  [9,]    0    3
#> [10,]    0    3
```

---

**EDIT**

If for some reason you want a loop, you need to simplify your logic and just use a single loop - since there are only two columns, you don't need to iterate through the columns, just compare column 1 to column 2 in each row. The following is a working example:

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(goals1)) {
    if(goals1[i, 1] > goals1[i, 2]) {
      points1[i, 1] <- 3
      points1[i, 2] <- 0
    } else if (goals1[i, 1] < goals1[i, 2]) {
      points1[i, 1] <- 0
      points1[i, 2] <- 3
    } else if (goals1[i, 1] == goals1[i, 2]) {
      points1[i, 1] <- 1
      points1[i, 2] <- 1
    }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I think it is clear to me what you did, big thanks! I want to know if it is possible to create in 1 step a matrix for the winpoints instead of making it as dataframe first?

Comment: @Wutruvic you could `cbind` the two vectors together instead of making them as a dataframe, but then you would need to also give the columns names. You could also just wrap the dataframe in `as.matrix` instead of using the pipe operator. Why is this important?

Comment: I am wondering if you can get the same result if you avoid using a loop and instead of using logical indexing? Is that also possible to obtain this result?

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, can you please explain me what I am doing wrong in my if and if else statements? I can't find what I am doing wrong in my code but I am desperate to fix it.

Comment: @Wutruvic there are a few problems with your own code. Your if statements aren't wrapped in parentheses, so this code doesn't even run in R. Secondly, it's not clear what you are doing with your loops. For example, in the very first iteration of the inner loop, you are checking `goals1[goals1[i]>goals1[j]]`, but since `i` and `j` are both 1,  this simplifies to `goals1[FALSE]`, which doesn't make any sense. Remember, you need to use both indices to specify the row and column you are referring to : `goal1[i, j]` for example. But the logic just doesn't make sense with your current code.

Comment: where do I need to add parentheses in my if statements? Secondly, I try to do the same with my loops as I explained, I try see in my loops who won the game and based on that result give points or not. So how could I interpret this into the if and if else statements correctly?

Comment: @Wutruvic see my update, where I have fixed your loop

Comment: Thanks! I now understand what I did wrong, I am really grateful!